# didChangeAppLifecycleState doesn't work as expected

Tags: flutter, dart, onresume

I hope I understand how `didChangeAppLifecycleState` worked correctly.

I have page A and page B . When I click the back device button from page B ( `Navigator.of(context).pop();` ), I expect `didChangeAppLifecycleState` in pageA will get called, but it doesn't.

PageA

```
class _ABCState extends State<ABCrList> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
            ....
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      setState(() {
        print(...);
      });
    }else{
      print(state.toString());
    }
  }

....
```

This is the `initState` in pageA. The function used to call backend service.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();  
       _bloc.getList(context);  // return list and populate to ListView
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The way you're thinking it is Android's way where `onResume` works, but in Flutter, things don't happen this way.

Generally, this gets called when the system puts the app in the background or returns the app to the foreground.

---

There are mainly 4 states for it:

`resumed`: The application is visible and responding to user input.

`inactive`: The application is in an inactive state and is not receiving user input.

`paused`: The application is not currently visible to the user, not responding user input, and running in the background.

`detached`: The application is still hosted on a flutter engine but is detached from any host views.

---

**Edit:**

When you're navigating to `PageB` from `PageA`, use something like:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/pageB").then((flag) {
  if (flag) {
    // you're back from PageB, perform your function here
    setState(() {}); // you may need to call this if you want to update UI
  }
});
```

And from PageB, you'll can use

```
Navigator.pop(context, true);
```

Comment: So if I want to call a function once back device button is pressed in pageB, where should I put?

Comment: You have `Navigator.push().then(_)` that can be used in `PageA`.

Comment: From PageB, you'll do `Navigator.pop(true)`, and in `PageA` you can get it's value which is represented by `_` in above code.

Comment: Can you check my post again? I have updated it. Currently `getList` will get called when page is loaded first time. When it back from pageB, how can I call the function again?

Comment: Thanks, by follow your code, I can see the function get called again. But data not populated to listView. Why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203514/discussion-between-tony-and-copsonroad).

Comment: @Tony How can check if application on background#

Comment: @user123456 not sure bro

Comment: What if someone is navigating from tab1 to tab2 ?

Comment: this worked. but didn't need the flag bool.

Comment: @janithcooray Yes, I agree with you but sometimes you don't want to refresh the page once you have navigated back from one section of a child widget. For situations like that you should use a flag which I probably thought of while writing this answer.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad oh so that's what the true in (context, true) was for. yes, that is very useful since the app would crash if it calls setState while background.